# CSS Sprite Animation not working as desired

Tags: css, animation, sprite

I'm using this code but with different units:

```
-webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
```

And

```
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from { background-position:    0px; }
    to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

See
http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

But I keep getting a side scrolling image, with this code:

```
$('html > head').append("<style class='"+name+" animation'>@-webkit-keyframes "+name+" {from {background-position:"+start+"px -"+y+"px;} to{ background-position: -"+end+"px -"+y+"px; }} ."+name+"{background-image: url(assets/images/"+image+".png); -webkit-animation: "+name+" "+duration+"s steps("+current_key.length+") infinite; width:"+w+"px; height: "+h+"px;}</style>");
```

I mean, the image does not change, it scrolls over the others over time and I'm trying to use CSS animation for sprite sheet animations for games.

I could not find the problem elsewhere, maybe i'm searching it wrong. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference between your code and the original is that in the original the sprite is already all the way to the left, so when the sprite scrolls you never see the white part of the next drawing and thus it does not look like it scrolls, if you set the  `from {background-position:100px;}` you will see the scrolling and you will undestand me better I believe, also I only tried with different values in the original code but if you put 4 steps instead of 10 although you won't see the complete animation you will see an animation that is close enough you can also use 9 I will take another look at it later to see if I can get you a better answer. It may help you here's the forked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhdGX/1/) so you can take a look at it.

**EDIT:**

After looking more closely at the animations property specially the steps function I realized that it moves the width of the image (50px) by the number of steps (10) giving us the -500px that we want to move. So for example if you want to have the sprite 300px to the right you would have to change the animation code like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes play {
from { background-position:    300px; }
to { background-position: -200px; }
}
```

insead of having -500px because this way you will have moved 300px already so you only need to move the -200px that you have left. So to summarize the formula to change these values is:
(`sprite_width` * `-number_steps`) - (`from_brackground_position`) = (to_background_position);
take note that number_steps is negative! also note that `from` and `to` can be used as percentages too. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWq9K/2/) that has the latest changes. If you have any more questions or comments feel free to ask/comment. Hope this helps! Thanks I'm glad I could help also I forgot to put a link to css-tricks where `steps()` function is explained very well and other `properties` of `css animations` used. Check it out if you like [here it is](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/). Greetings from Mexico!

Comment: Well I already had my code 90% done, I had an Extra -32px (tile width) because i though I needed to get the corner of the image to... whatever, your formula allowed me to check my results and adapt my code in literally 10 seconds! Thanks for answering so fast and greetings from Argentina!